# Using leftrightharpoon in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-arrows

Is it possible to use \leftrightharpoons in a tikzcd diagram? In the documentation it looks like I can use only single-sided harpoons in tikz...

[image: leftrightharpoons]

Answer (score 4):

You can make them:

[image]

The `\tikzcdset` is basically the same as `\tikzset` except the macros defined will be used, you guessed right, with Ti*k*Z-CD.

I basically copied the definition of the built-in harpoons and changed the arrow ends. The `right to` and `left to` arrow tips are part of `tikzcd`.

As for the arrow you posted in you edit to your question, I didn't find a "clean" way of doing it. But that's basically two harpoons with diverging `yshift`s.

I defined a macro in the same fashion that the standard `\arrow`: `\leftrightharpoon[...]`. The macro takes as argument the direction of the arrow and any other Ti*k*Z-compatible options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\tikzcdset{%
   harpoonlurd/.code={\pgfsetarrows{tikzcd right to-tikzcd right to}},
   harpoonldru/.code={\pgfsetarrows{tikzcd left to-tikzcd left to}},
   harpoonluru/.code={\pgfsetarrows{tikzcd right to-tikzcd left to}},
   harpoonldrd/.code={\pgfsetarrows{tikzcd left to-tikzcd right to}},
}
\makeatletter
\def\leftrightharpoon{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\@lrharp}{\@lrharp[]}%
}
\def\@lrharp[#1]{%
  \arrow[#1, leftharpoonup  ,yshift= 0.225ex]%
  \arrow[#1,rightharpoondown,yshift=-0.225ex]%
}
\makeatother
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \arrow[r,harpoonlurd] & B\\
  A \arrow[r,harpoonldru] & B\\
  A \arrow[r,harpoonluru] & B\\
  A \arrow[r,harpoonldrd] & B\\
  A \leftrightharpoon[r] & B\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

P.S.: Feel free to rename them. I'm not the most creative human being :P

Comment: Thanks! I don't think I understand how tikzcdset works yet--I have reading to do. Also, is it possible to make the arrow that I've added as a picture to the question itself?

Comment: Great suggestion for a single arrow, but I am having trouble figuring out how to do a double arrow like \leftrightharpoons. Do you also know how to do this?

Comment: @Rachel Naughty you, editing the question after someone answered :P You'll hardly get an answer to the edited question, because we don't get a notification for the edit, the same way you didn't get a notification for my edit to the answer. Next time I suggest you post a new question. Anyway, see the edit above, I think that's what you want :)